# Astro Image Exceeds Pixel Limit

Tags: astrojs

My Astro site fails to build (`pnpm run build`) while optimizing images.
I get this error:

```
 ▶ /_astro/slide_10.59a099b8_1QqCBS.webp (before: 48kB, after: 18kB) (+215ms) (40/65)
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[Error: Input image exceeds pixel limit]

Node.js v20.9.0
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

It is unclear what image is causing the build to fail.
How can I fix this issue without manually compressing all images?

Comment: It is three gifs from 8.8 Mb to 9.7 Mb causing the build to fail. I am dissapointed Astro can't optimize these like Gatsby did.

Comment: Which Astro version are you using?

Comment: @Alex I am using 3.5.4.

Comment: Interesting - I tested with images above 10MB on that Astro version and it built fine. Does it build if you just use one of those GIFs? That error seems to be coming from Sharp, do you have `sharp` as a separate dependency in your project? If so, try updating it as well.

Comment: I do not have Sharp installed as a seperate dependency. Using just one of the 9.7Mb gifs causes the error.